# Fixing horizontal axis in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, plot, scaling

I have the following plot and I would like to have the horizental axis fixed, but it scales and therefore I cannot see the details of the values between 0-50. To be more specific, in the horizental axis, I have information about the size of the files, so the axis should not scale according the number.

On the other hand, I would like to set the size of plot manually because of that I have the following line :

```
\pgfplotsset{width=20cm, height=15cm}


\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    title={Results},
    xlabel={Size of file},
    ylabel={The amount of time per second},
    xmin=0, xmax=2200,
    ymin=0, ymax=600,
    xtick={1,5,10,100,500,1000,2000},
    ytick={0,5,10,20,30,40,50,100,150,200,300,400,500},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
]

\addplot[
    color=red,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (1,4.5)(10,7)(100,26)(500,113)(1000,278)(2000,0)
    };
     \addlegendentry {existing}

    \addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=triangle,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (1,4.5)(10,6.5)(100,21)(500,86)(1000,177)(2000,398)
    };
    \addlegendentry {Partitioning}

    \addplot[
    color=green,
    mark=star,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (1,0.2)(10,1.2)(100,14.5)(500,0)(1000,0)(2000,0)
    };
    \addlegendentry {Model}


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Sounds like you want `symbolic x coords`, see e.g. [Using pgfplots with x-axis that is not evenly distributed](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/298712)